# Parse XML using libxml2

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, libxml2

I am trying from almost a day to parse the below XML using libxml2 cpp library. I need to 2 things:

1) I need to get the list of all "Bucket" tag in a std::vector array.

2) Find if "NextMarker" tag is present or not.

Their are 2 possible XML that can be given as input.

**XML 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<EnumerationResults ServiceEndpoint="https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/">  
  <MaxResults>3</MaxResults>  
  <Containers>  
    <Bucket>  
      <Name>audio</Name>  
      <Properties>  
        <Last-Modified>Wed, 26 Oct 2016 20:39:39 GMT</Last-Modified>  
        <Etag>0x8CACB9BD7C6B1B2</Etag> 
        <PublicAccess>container</PublicAccess> 
      </Properties>  
    </Bucket>  
    <Bucket>  
      <Name>images</Name>  
      <Properties>  
        <Last-Modified>Wed, 26 Oct 2016 20:39:39 GMT</Last-Modified>  
        <Etag>0x8CACB9BD7C1EEEC</Etag>  
      </Properties>  
    </Bucket>  
    <Bucket>  
      <Name>textfiles</Name>  
      <Properties>  
        <Last-Modified>Wed, 26 Oct 2016 20:39:39 GMT</Last-Modified>  
        <Etag>0x8CACB9BD7BACAC3</Etag>  
      </Properties>  
    </Bucket>  
  </Containers>  
  <NextMarker>video</NextMarker>  
</EnumerationResults>
```

**XML 2**

```
<EnumerationResults>
    <Containers />
    <NextMarkerr>/pdtcava01a/container1</NextMarker>
</EnumerationReslts>
```

My poor code:

```
int main(){
    // Read the file
    xmlDocPtr doc; /* the resulting document tree */
    doc = xmlReadFile("/home/cbs/hemant/azure_d_patch/backend_trim/file_xml.xml", NULL, 0);

    // Thing#2. Check if NextMarker tag is present. WORKING
    xmlNode *root = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
    xmlNodePtr lastChild = root->last->prev;
    xmlChar *NextMarker = xmlCharStrdup("NextMarker");
    if(!xmlStrcmp(lastChild->name, NextMarker)) {
        cout<<"NextMarker tag present"<<endl;
    }

    // thing#1. Failing to get the list of Buckets. NOT WORKING
    xmlChar *toFind = xmlCharStrdup("Containers");
    xmlNodePtr container = findNodeByName(root->children, toFind);
    container = container->children;

    XmlVal hem(container->children);
    std::vector<XmlVal> cont_list = hem.list(); // list() was my internal function which I now scraped.

    for (std::vector<XmlVal>::iterator it = cont_list.begin(); it != cont_list.end(); ++it) {
        bucket b;
        b.name_ = (*it)["Name"].content();
        b.creation_time_ = (*it)["Last-Modified"].content();
        cout<<b.name_<<"    "<<b.creation_time_<<endl;
        bucket_list.push_back(b);
    }
    return 1;

}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question... What is happening? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @Thomas.....Hey thanks I edited the que. Somehow I am not getting the libxml2 right. Frankly speaking I didn't understand its documentation and complexity.

Comment: @HemantYadav You haven't asked a question or described a problem, you've only shared your goals. What output are you getting? What output are you expecting? How do they differ? Are you getting errors? If you do, what kind and what do they say? Take a moment to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: See the line number 8. I was expecting the lastChild->name to return name of tag, but it always returns "text" as output. So I am stuck at initial stage only.

Comment: It worked, I am able to check the whether NextMarker is present or not. Code need be changed to xmlNodePtr lastChild = root->last->prev;        But why root->last->prev when last child is "NextMarker" tag. @François Andrieux @ Thomas

Comment: Modified the code in the question. Now still Thing#1 is left.